# Class 'Craft' not found

Tags: error-message, classes, plugin-recaptcha

I am new to PHP and trying to call reCaptcha API in CraftCMS. I have the following variable:

```
$captcha = Craft::$app->getRequest()->getParam('g-recaptcha-response');
```

But I get the following error when I submit a form:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Craft' not found
```

How can I import the Craft class?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really specific to Craft, but you should import `Craft` at the beginning of your class file like this:

```php
<?php

use Craft;

...
```

I suggest you take a look at that documentation for more details about how to import PHP classes: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: use Craft; gave the following error:
Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'Craft' has no effect

Comment: In what context are you using the Craft object? Are you using a Module ou a Plugin? If not, you should include the Framework autoloader from the `vendors` folder in order to use its classes. You will find an example of how to do that by looking to the `index.php` file in the `web` folder of your project. However, in your use case, using a Module looks like the way to go.